# How do I check or uncheck by using checkbox in SectionList In React Native

Tags: react-native, checkbox, react-native-sectionlist

How do I check or uncheck by using checkbox in SectionList In React Native.
without using third-party module.

Answer (score 1):

renderItem() prop let you render whatever you want in your list items.
You could:

```
<Checkbox
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onCheck={e => this.setState({ checked: e.target.checked})}/>
```